# Is there any papers about simulating material damage under supersonic combustion?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, solid-mechanics

I'm quite interested in this field, Is there any papers about simulating the damage of material(such as alloy) under supersonic combustion, after searching for a while, I didn't find anything